# Convertir un string con coma a int en java

Tags: java, string, conversión-de-tipos

Como convierto una cadena con una coma como separador de miles a una variable de tipo entero o flotante? por ejemplo si tengo un string "1,200" poder convertirlo a un entero y que quede solo 1200?

Comment: Hola @sasuke39 ,he emitido un voto de cierre por que considero que a tu pregunta le falta un ejemplo de código para poder reproducir lo que intentas hacer; la plataforma  no ha utilizado; este motivo al momento de mostrarte la ayuda; considero que es mi deber hacer esta aclaración; ya que creo que tu post tiene los detalles o aclaración de lo que pretendes.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque como ya te han dicho puedes hacer un replace, si estás trabajando con unidades de monedas por ejemplo donde se usan separadores de miles y de decimales y dependen de la forma de escritura del país del que provienen, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String entrada = "1,200";
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("us", "US"));
        Integer salida = nf.parse(entrada).intValue();
        System.out.println(salida);
    }
}
```

Lo que se hace es aplicarle un formateador de números indicando que se está usando el sistema estadounidense (comas para separar miles, puntos para separar los decimales).

Ese formateador de números puede descifrar tu string y saber que hay que ignorar la coma de los miles. Al llamar a parse, devuelve un objeto `Number` que luego puedes convertir a entero, double o lo que necesites.

Esto también te ayudará a validar la entrada, ya que se generará una `ParseException` en caso de que no esté bien escrita.

Más info:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un de **replace()** para reemplazar al "," por un vacio "" ,luego lo conviertes a int o float
Lo que hace **replace()** es buscar una expresión regular y la reemplaza por otra

```
    String num="1,200";
    String num2=num.replace(",","");
    int num3=Integer.parseInt(num2);
    System.out.println(num3);
```

de manera simplificada :

```
int numero=Integer.parseInt(num.replace(",",""));
```